# В какой памяти хранятся указатели?

Tags: c#, указатели

Есть код:

```
int a = 6;
int* b = &a;
```

Так вот вопрос: в какой памяти хранится указатель b? В стеке?

Comment: Напрашивается ответ "в оперативной, но это не точно". Вопрос контекстозависимый, при этом задан вне контекста. Чтобы узнать ответ, нужно смотреть сгенерированный IL код всего метода.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Локальные переменные в C# могут храниться либо в регистрах, либо в стеке.

Стек более "медленный", чем регистры, но он больше (обычно 1 МБ в Windows) и от переменных в стеке можно брать адрес; также в стеке можно хранить переменные любого размера. В вашем случае переменная `a` хранится в стеке, т. к. след. строчкой вы у неё берёте адрес.

Регистры быстрее стека, но они меньше по размеру (размер зависит от процессора, обычно <100 байт) и от переменных в регистрах адрес брать нельзя; также в регистрах можно хранить переменные размером в 2, 4 и 8 байт (почти всегда размер указателя). Т. е. переменная `b` скорее всего будет храниться в регистах.

Почему «скорее всего»? Дело в том, что мы не управляем распределением переменных на прямую – это делает компилятор (IL → Native, компилятор C# → IL просто добавляет `push` IL-инструкции), а так как реализация компилятора уникальна для каждой платформы (у .NET своя, у Mono своя и т. д.), то он может расположить переменную `b` где угодно, но понятно, что скорее всего (по крайней мере в .NET так) он будет располагать её в регистрах.

#### ДОПИНг (ДОПолнительная ИНформация)

- [Регистры](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0)
- [Стек](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2)
- [Кэш](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%8D%D1%88)

Comment: Регистры вообще не принято называть "памятью". Регистры - это регистры, память - это память. А если нырнуть глубже на самый низкий уровень, то там еще 2-3 уровня кеша процессора нарисуются.

Comment: @aepot Тогда каким общим словом назвать регистры и память? Я знаю про кэш, но моя интуиция мне подсказывает, что автору это пока не нужно (всё же добавлю ссылку в ДОПИНг на кэш).

Comment: Да никаким, значение "может храниться в регистре процессора, или в памяти". Так же, термин "регистр - самая быстрая память", это весьма странное утверждение, потому что процессору, чтобы что-то вычислить, надо это загрузить в регистры, там есть "скорость", а чтобы вычислить то, что уже находится в регистрах, нужно только выполнить вычислительную  инструкцию. Если только под скоростью понимать копирование значения из одного регистра в другой, но у меня все равно это в голове не укладывается: зачем копировать, если можно сразу выполнить инструкцию? Но ваш ответ правильный, если глубже не копать.

Comment: @aepot так тут и не нужно глубже копать: я всё узнал из гугла, думаю, автор сделает тоже самое. По поводу регистра: это напоминает проблему гипотезы и теории, но всё же я заменю конфликтные слова в ответе, чтобы в дальнейшем не было путаницы.

Comment: Я утверждаю на основе практики написания кода на ассемблере. А по поводу скорости, вот подсказка на погуглить: что быстрее (допустим, это Intel процессор), `mov eax, ebx`, или `push eax` `pop ebx`? Наглядное сравнение скорости стека и скорости копирования регистра.

Comment: @aepot это мне писать или как XD

Comment: Это не писать, а просто для себя, для общего развития. Там много интересных штук в этом процессоре происходит. Например нельзя просто так взять и напрямую скопировать значение из одной ячейки памяти в другую, придется сначала прочитать его в регистр, и только потом записать по новому адресу в памяти, но на помощь приходит DMA, и все становится еще веселее. Или почему `eax` называют аккумулятором, и чем он отличается от других регистров, тоже не менее увлекательная история, но там где-то и кроются все ответы про скорость, и про то, откуда взялся вообще IL, и как транслятор IL оптимизирует код.

Comment: @aepot где-то я это слышал (или видел?) в недавно прочитанной "К.О.Д."... На самом деле я почти сразу узнал почему аккамулятор... аккамулятор (гугл в помощь)!

Comment: @aepot да, LL это ещё та Санта-Барбара)

Comment: @aepot про аккамулятор – я думал, что это как-то связанно с машинным аккамулятором... понимаю)